# Handle user input type mismatch in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I am building a basic program in Silverfrost FTN5 wherein I input an integer from user.
If user enters a float value, it throws an error and the program ends. Is there any way I can handle this invalid input and ask user to enter valid input?

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods.  1) Read the input into a string and parse the string.  If the string contains a period, reject it and re-ask for input.  If the string appears valid, do an "internal" read of the integer from the string: `read (string, *) IntVal`.  2) More robust since this gracefully detects all errors: use the `IOSTAT=` keyword in your read statement.  If the value is non-zero, there was an error ... re-ask for input.

EDIT: Code example:

```
program TestRead

integer :: number, ReadStatus

write (*, '( "Input integer: " )', advance="no" )
ReadInt: do
   read (*, *, iostat=ReadStatus) number
   if ( ReadStatus == 0 ) then
      exit ReadInt
   else
      write (*, '( / "READ ERROR: please re-input:" )' )
   end if
end do ReadInt

write (*, '( / "Value read: ", I0 )' )  number

end program TestRead
```

Comment: can you explain how to use IOSTAT for this application?

Comment: worth a note, approach 1 has a big advantage in that you can see/handle whatever invalid thing the user entered. Let them type 'abort' to exit gracefully for example.