# Reading missing data from a file

Tags: fortran

I have to read a file that contains numerical data (mostly reals) but there are also some missing data that are denoted by an asterisk(*). I don't know the positions of the asterisks in advance and I have to find the total valid (numerical) data and the total missing data (asterisks).

I tried doing this with a 'select case' nested in a do loop but failed because

1. I can't use real type for the selector
2. I don't think I can put the asterisks in a real matrix

The data file looks something like this

```
1    0.673070
2    0.750597
3    *
4    0.484100
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without showing your attempt we haven't much to go on and the question is very broad.  However, you can find a good hint in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17187654/3157076).  If you something like that and you still have trouble, please [edit] this question with those details.

Comment: We really need much more information. Details about the file, your code and so on... See [ask]

Comment: I suggest OP edits the data file with something like `sed` or her favourite editor and delete all the `*`.  It's easier to write code to deal with missing values than to deal with a value which might parse as a real or might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know every line has either a real number or an *, I would do something like this:

```
Character(len=8) :: LineRead
Real :: RealNumber
open(42,file='MyFile.txt')

do (whichever kind of loop you need to control the input)
   read(42,'(a8)') LineRead
   if (LineRead <> '*       ')
     read(LineRead,'(f8.6)') RealNumber
     ! Increment some sort of valid data counter
   end if
end do
```

This technique is called reading from an internal file. Any character variable can be 'read' this way.

Comment: I did not add any code because I knew that what I had at the point was totally wrong. Eventually, I figured out how to solve the problem myself, using `iostat`. I am indeed not familiar with the technique you used! Thanks for posting it!